# AWS Lighsail Website using Runcloud says Website Unavailable

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, amazon-lightsail

I am currently using Runcloud with my AWS Lighsail Ubuntu server. Everything is connected in the panel section but for some reason my website is no longer available and I'm not sure why.

Does anyone have any experience with Runcloud or know why my website isn't displaying?

http://18.217.248.187

Edit:

After trying to run the following terminal command:

`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart`

I get the following error:

```
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : apache not running
/opt/bitnami/php/scripts/ctl.sh : php-fpm stopped
/opt/bitnami/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql not running
/opt/bitnami/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql  could not be started
/opt/bitnami/php/scripts/ctl.sh : php-fpm started
Syntax OK
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to 
address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to 
address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd could not be started
```

Edit 2:

using `ps -e | grep 3490` I get:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               
LISTEN      1501/nginx-rc   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    
LISTEN      1501/nginx-rc
```

Followed by `ps -ef |grep 1501` which resulted in:

```
root      1501     1  0 Jan08 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process 
/usr/local/sbin/nginx-rc
runclou+  1510  1501  0 Jan08 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
bitnami  22205 19362  0 00:50 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 1501
```

When trying to run `killall httpd` I get the following error:

```
httpd(8068): Operation not permitted
httpd(8069): Operation not permitted
httpd(8070): Operation not permitted
httpd(8071): Operation not permitted
httpd: no process found
```

All of this looks like a different language to me as I am just trying to understand why my errors are happening and how to fix them.

How do I fix this error or get httpd and mysql to run?

Comment: You need to be root to kill it.  Try 'sudo killall httpd'.  The 'sudo' command is 'superuser do', and is a common way for non-root users to execute root commands, without having to login as root.  Also, there is a hugely flexible way to allow and/or deny access to different users, and limit their privileges however yo want.  The scope of that is way beyond the current subject, but you should be aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be these two lines:

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to 
address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to 
address 0.0.0.0:80
```

The first line says that TCPv6 port 80 is already in use, and the second line says the same for TCPv4.

To attempt solving this, first figure out what program is running using port 80:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
```

Which should produce output similar to:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      3490/httpd
```

In my case, the `:::80` shows the Source port, and the `3490/httpd` tells me the pid and the name of the process.

You might then do:

```
ps -ef|grep 3490
```

Which may output something like:

```
root      3490     1  0 Jan04 ?        00:00:11 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   27032  3490  0 12:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   27862  3490  0 13:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   28195  3490  0 13:29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   28285  3490  0 13:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   28568  3490  0 13:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   28569  3490  0 13:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   30052  3490  0 14:33 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   30161  3490  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   30165  3490  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   30470  3490  0 14:48 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
oracle   31591 31560  0 15:26 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 3490
```

Which shows multiple httpd processes running.

`sudo killall httpd` should clear up any processes running on port 80.

Then try starting again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you installed bitnami package while having RunCloud setup on the same server.

RunCloud requires a fresh installation (no other web server installed) to install RunCloud server stack and RunCloud agent. Then you can manage the server's services via RunCloud panel.

Installing other server stack will conflict with the existing RunCloud stack.